# How to load data and save data from database in drupal using json

Tags: json, drupal-6

Load data from server side and save modified data to server side (database)using json in drupal module

Comment: imho you need to be a bit more specific. is it a one off thing? multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

To access data on remote via any kind of protocol http://drupal.org/project/Services is a good solution.

There is a lot of documentation availible